# Looking for examples on how to use spring-data RedisZSetCommands.zRangeByLex

Tags: java, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

Specially, I need to know:

1. How Range's gt, gte, lt, and lte methods work.
2. Is there a way to peek just one item? For ex. from command line it is possible to do:

> zadd test 0 aaaa
>   (integer) 1
>
> zadd test 0 bbbb
>   (integer) 1
>
> zadd test 0 aa
>   (integer) 1
>
> zadd test 0 aaaaaa
>   (integer) 1
>
> **zrangebylex test [aaaa [aaaa**
>   1) "aaaa"

Can the same be done using RedisZSetCommands.zRangeByLex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for `ZRANGEBYLEX` directly via `ZSetOperations` and `RedisZSet` is still an open issue. Though it is possible using `RedisCallback`.

```java
template.execute(new RedisCallback<Set<byte[]>>() {

  @Override
  public Set<byte[]> doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
    return connection.zRangeByLex(key, Range.range().gte("aaaa").lte("aaaa"));
  }
});
```

Comment: Christoph, thank. It worked. What do you mean by open issue?

Comment: the open issue means, that there should be support for `zRangeByLex` via `template.opsForZSet()` which has not been implemented yet.

Comment: For anyone reading this, opsForZSet is now implemented